# Не удаётся брать глобальную переменную (Бот Aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Недавно сделал отправку форм сообщений по телеграм каналам. Сделал и всё работало, на следующий день я ничего не трогал но всё перестало работать. Это случилось после того как я **попытался** закинуть бота на гитхаб для вебхука.

Это часть кода показывающая проблему:

sqlite_db:

```
import sqlite3 as sq
from create_bot import bot
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
import logging

WOMEN_CLOTHES_ID = '-1001725156351'

def sql_start():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('pizza_cool.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('Data base connect OK!')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(img TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT, price TEXT)')
    base.commit()

async def sql_add_command(state):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
        base.commit()

async def WOMEN_CLOTHES(message):
    global ret
    for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall():
        pass
    await bot.send_photo(WOMEN_CLOTHES_ID, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена: {ret[-1]}')

async def sql_read2():
    return cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall()
```

В другом коде происходит вызов этих функций:

admin.py:

```
async def test(message: types.Message):
    await sqlite_db.WOMEN_CLOTHES(message)
```

```
def register_handler_admin(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(test, commands='test')
```

В первом коде ещё происходит внесение данных в базу но там ошибок нет, перепроверил несколько раз)

Но если захотите проверить то скину полностью код

При запуске бота ошибок не происходит, но выходит при попытке занести что то в базу данных

> await bot.send_photo(WOMEN_CLOTHES_ID, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена: {ret[-1]}')
> NameError: name 'ret' is not defined

Вот картинка как расположены файлы:
[image: Расположение]

Заранее спасибо :з

Comment: 1) Что-то вы точно сделали. Код сам себя не модифицирует. "После того" не значит "вследствие того". 2) для начала поставьте простейшую отладочную печать `print (ret)` прямо перед строкой с ошибкой, да посмотрите внимательно на свой `ret` - как он выглядит, и что от него ожидается (или в отладчике посмотрите). Должны увидеть список с, как минимум, четыремя элементами, да ещё и, вероятно, условиям удовлетворяющим неким.

Comment: Проект разрабатывался 2 людьми, но ни я ни другой разработчик ничего с кодом с того дня не делали, я только попытался закинуть на гитхаб, но что то не вышло. Я только что попытался вывести ret на команду test, при этом закомментировал строку с bot.send_photo

Но выводиться     print(ret)
NameError: name 'ret' is not defined

Comment: Причём переменная глобальная @Сергей

Comment: 1) Код сам собой не меняется. Так просто не может быть. Возьмите версию, что была до помещения на github. 2) Мало того, что `global` вообще не лучшая практика, так вы ей ещё и магические свойства приписываете. У вас прямо в этой функции `ret` в цикле должен же определяться, при чём тут её глобальность? Я не знаю, что должна делать `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall()`, но, судя по всему, она это не делает.